# What rights are required for IIS to talk a WCF service hosted on a different machine?

Tags: wcf, iis

In this question: [ASP.NET web application unable to connect to WCF hosted as windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963534/asp-net-web-application-unable-to-connect-to-wcf-hosted-as-windows-service)

it's stated that the reason IIS could not talk to a WCF service hosted on a different machine is due to rights not assigned the app pool identity.

I'm facing the same problem I believe. What are these rights, and where do I set them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the configuration of the service you're trying to access.  However, if you're having trouble connecting to a different machine, you most likely don't have rights to access that computer using the machine account for the server hosting IIS.  You could try adding [domain][iismachine] access to the target server (the one hosting the WCF service).

[This overview](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) has some pretty good information on what needs to be done in different scenarios.

Comment: Can't quite see what I would grant the ACL on precisely, on the target machine. I should also mention this is a non-domain scenario.